# Get unique values from array values in json array

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a code where I need to return uniques values from a JSON array. Here my challenge is, I've got these values as an array for one of the keys.

Here is my code.

```js
let mobilePhones = [{
  id: 1,
  brand: ["B1", "B2"]
}, {
  id: 2,
  brand: ["B2"]
}, {
  id: 3,
  brand: ["B1", "B2"]
}, {
  id: 4,
  brand: ["B1"]
}, {
  id: 5,
  brand: ["B2", "B1"]
}, {
  id: 6,
  brand: ["B3"]
}]
let allBrandsArr = mobilePhones.map(row => {
  return row.brand;
});
let uniqueBrands = allBrandsArr.filter((item, index, arry) => (arry.indexOf(item) === index));
console.log(JSON.stringify(uniqueBrands));
```

Here my expected result is to get `["B1", "B2", "B3"]`. Please let me know how can I achieve this.

**Updated new sample data:**

```
let mobilePhones = [{
      id: 1,
      brand: ["B1, B2"]
    }, {
      id: 2,
      brand: ["B2"]
    }, {
      id: 3,
      brand: ["B1, B2"]
    }, {
      id: 4,
      brand: ["B1"]
    }, {
      id: 5,
      brand: ["B2, B1"]
    }, {
      id: 6,
      brand: ["B3"]
    }]
    let allBrandsArr = mobilePhones.map(row => {
      return row.brand;
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `flat` for merge sub array then your code was good:

```js
let mobilePhones = [{
  id: 1,
  brand: ["B1, B2"]
}, {
  id: 2,
  brand: ["B2"]
}, {
  id: 3,
  brand: ["B1, B2"]
}, {
  id: 4,
  brand: ["B1"]
}, {
  id: 5,
  brand: ["B2, B1"]
}, {
  id: 6,
  brand: ["B3"]
}]
let allBrandsArr = mobilePhones.map(row => {
  return row.brand[0].split(',').map(function(item) {
    return item.trim();
  });
});
let uniqueBrands = allBrandsArr.flat().filter((item, index, arry) => (arry.indexOf(item) === index));
console.log(JSON.stringify(uniqueBrands));
```

Reference:

- [Array.prototype.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

---

After new Data posted i add `split` with `trim`.

Reference:

- [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [String.prototype.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

Comment: Thanks for this Simone. I've seen another pattern in my data it is like `["B1, B2"]` and also `["B1", "B2"]`. How can I handle these cases? I just updated my question.

Comment: I add support for new data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to get all the brand values and pass it to a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to make it unique.

```
const uniqueBrands = [...new Set(mobilePhones.flatMap(({
  brand
}) => brand))];
```

```js
let mobilePhones = [{
  id: 1,
  brand: ["B1", "B2"]
}, {
  id: 2,
  brand: ["B2"]
}, {
  id: 3,
  brand: ["B1", "B2"]
}, {
  id: 4,
  brand: ["B1"]
}, {
  id: 5,
  brand: ["B2", "B1"]
}, {
  id: 6,
  brand: ["B3"]
}]

const unique = [...new Set(mobilePhones.flatMap(({
  brand
}) => brand))];

console.log(unique);
```

Comment: Thanks, Gabriele for this. I have a case where I can have data in both formats `["B1, B2"]` or `["B1", "B2"]`. How can I handle them? Updated my question